# How to launch a web page after installation with ClickOnce

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installation, clickonce

Is it possible to launch an URL after a ClickOnce installer finishes?

Comment: [How to specify a Publish Page for a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws69w0k3.aspx)

Comment: I don't think a public page is the solution, what I want to achieve is to launch a web page when the installation finishes. I think the publish page is where the software is published.